# Error "The batch could not be analyzed because of compile errors in ssis" in execute sql task while passing with output parameter for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am using `sp_send_dbmail` to get the `mailitem_id` as output. When I run the query with output parameter

[image]

it's throwing below error and without output it's working fine.

> Error: Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec ? = sp_send_dbmail @profile_name=?, @recipien..." failed with the following error:
>   The batch could not be analyzed because of compile errors.
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Query:

```
exec ? = sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = ?, @recipients = ?, 
                        @copy_recipients = ?, @subject = ?,
                        @body = ?, @importance = ?,
                        @body_format = ?@mailitem_id = ? OUT
```

`@mailitem_id` is `OUTPUT` parameter in the stored procedure, and of `INT` type..

I tried different methods to pass output parameter but still getting same error... Is it failing with the datatype mismatch or syntax error with passing output parameter unable to get it..

Please help me to resolve the issue..I have added the parameter mapping window in the screen shot. I have tried with `Short`, `ULarge_integer` and `Large_integer` types also instead of `Long` in parameter mapping for `mailitem_id`.

Comment: what is the connection type are you using? ADO.net or OLE DB

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `,` *just before* the `@mailitem_id` parameter .....

Comment: also, use `OUTPUT`, not `OUT` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Could be one of several things described in the error message, or all of them. I'll work through the error message in the order it is presented.

### Resolving the error message

> Problems with the query

1. When using the `EXEC @return_status = ...` syntax, the T-SQL variable must be defined with the `@` symbol. The variable must also be declared, so `EXEC ?` would only be logical if parameter `0` is passed in as a value such as `@return_value`.
2. As marc_s commented, the script is missing a comma between two parameters: `@body_format = ?@mailitem_id`.
3. `@mailitem_id = ? OUT` is not the correct syntax for this an output parameter, unless the parameter position for `?` is defined as a variable declared within the script (similar to issue #1).

The query should probably look something like this:

```
DECLARE @return_status INT, @mailitem_id INT;
EXEC @return_status = sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = ?, @recipients = ?, 
    @copy_recipients = ?, @subject = ?,
    @body = ?, @importance = ?,
    @body_format = ?, @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT
SELECT @return_status AS return_status, @mailitem_id AS mailitem_id;
```

For some examples of executing this stored procedure, see the [`sp_send_dbmail` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql).

> "ResultSet" property not set correctly

In the **General** tab of the **Execute SQL Task Editor**, what is the value of `ResultSet` in the `Result Set` group?

The options are:

- `None` - the query returns no results
- `Single row` - the query returns only one row
- `Full result set` - the query returns multiple rows
- `XML` - the query returns a result set in XML format

Ensure the selected option coincides with how your script is providing the result set and the rest of the task configuration is configured to handle it.

> parameters not set correctly

The **Result Set** tab on the left-hand side of the **Execute SQL Task Editor** is where parameters from the query should be mapped to SSIS variables. Ensure the mapped variables you are expecting are mapped here according to the `ResultSet` you chose in the **General** tab.

### Putting it all together

Using the code I provided under "Problems with the query," you would then set the `ResultSet` property in the **General** tab of the **Execute SQL Task Editor** to be `Single row`. Then, in the **Result Set** tab, you would map the column values returned from the script (`return_status` and `mailitem_id`) to SSIS variables (e.g. `User::Status` and `User::mailitem_id` as shown in your screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working fine with below query and getting mailitem_id as output.

```
exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name=?,@recipients=?,@copy_recipients=?,@subject=?,@body=?,@importance=?,@body_format=?,@mailitem_id= ? OUTPUT
```

Comment: You should probably mark @Joey 's answer as correct